# adding css classes into a specific image field

Tags: media, theming

is there a way to add css classes **only** to specific image field?

with the image field name **field_news_images**:

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="../images/something.png"/>
```

There are no options to add the classes in the manage display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to your theme's template.php function:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_news_images') {
    foreach($vars['items'] as $key => $item){
      $vars['items'][ $key ]['#item']['attributes']['class'][] = 'thumbnail';
    }
  }
}
```

Clear the cache.

Answer (score 7):

As of Drupal 8.2

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_news_images') {
    foreach($vars['items'] as $key => $item){
      $vars['items'][ $key ]['content']['#item_attributes']['class'][] = 'thumbnail';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Field formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class) module provides this functionality

1. This module allows site administrators to add classes to the outer HTML wrapper for any field display.
2. Classes can be specified at the Manage display settings for content types, users and other entities