# How to appened a new 'class' attribute to a custom field ? - twig drupal 8

Tags: theming, 8

Just started to work around with Drupal 8.

I want to add class "center-block" to the field_product_image.

```
<img class="img-responsive {new class}"/>
```

How do i do this guys?
below is the twig code

```
   {% if content.field_product_image| render %}
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    {{ content.field_product_image }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        {{ content.body }}
        {{ content.field_features }}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [Extra Image Field Classes](https://www.drupal.org/project/extra_image_field_classes) module.

This module will help in adding custom classes to image field.

Extra Image Field Classes module will allow users to apply css class to image field.

> How to add custom classes to image field
>
> 1. Go to "Manage Display" of an entity type
> 2. Select "Extra Image Field Classes" format from Format column for image field
> 3. Click on settings wheel of the image field
> 4. Enter css classes in Image Class textfield
> 5. Click "Update" button
> 6. Remember to click "Save" button after making necessary changes.

Also Go for hook_preprocess_field()

[Adding a class to default images in Drupal 8](https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/adding-css-classes-fields-drupal)

[Add class to field in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2865765)

[adding css classes into a specific image field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/142196/adding-css-classes-into-a-specific-image-field)

Comment: Thanks for this it works perfect for image fields and thanks for the info I checked all solutions and finally thought i should use the module.

Answer (score 7):

Normally I would say to call `addClass()` on the `image.attributes` variable in your image Twig file, but I believe images don't have a lot of template suggestions (everything goes through `image.html.twig`) which means that your class will be added to all images. Likely not what you're looking for...

Option one, inspect the variables in `image.html.twig` and see if they give you the information you need to determine when to add the new class. If so, do it in the Twig template (`attributes.addClass('new-class')`).

Option two, implement hook_preprocess_image in your theme's `.theme` file. Something like this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  if (some_way_to_figure_out_if_this_is_the_right_image) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'new-class';
  }
}
```

Hope that helps. (Edited for better code formatting).

Comment: Hi Mikeker thanks for all this. yes I have seen  the image.html.twig file it dose not give the information I need. If there was a node_type information in the `attributes` it could have been easy to add this using the twig code.

however the [extra image field classes ](https://www.drupal.org/project/extra_image_field_classes) module did the job. so i marked that as the answer.

Comment: `function mmboots_preprocess_image_formatter(&$variables)
{    
    $bundles = $item['item']->getFieldDefinition()->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getBundles();
    $key= array_keys($bundles); 
    $variables['image']['#attributes']['type']=$key[0];
    
}`
I saw the hook 'image_formatter' get called before the hook 'image' in the debug mode and was able to inject node_type to attributes.   then i was able to call it from the `image.html.twig`. hook_image didn't had what i looked for. 

Do you know whether drupal twig got any global variables we can call in a twig file ?. like $node?